# Assistance needed with variables in classes

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with variables in classes.

Say I have this class:

```
some_number = 200

class Numbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = some_number
    def edit(self):
        self.number = self.number - 50
    def printNumber(self):
        print(self.number)
```

If I run this in the shell:

```
number = Numbers()
number.edit()
number.printNumber()
```

This prints the number 150
But this:

```
print(some_number)
```

Prints the number 200. How do I get the variable some_number to change in a class, after which printing it returns the edited value?

Comment: Creating a class which depends on a global variable doesn't seem like good design. What is the motivation for that?

Comment: You could just reassign it in `edit` like you're doing with `self.number` after saying `global some_number`. Are you sure you need to do this though? Why give the object an internal state, then change both the internal and external state?

Comment: A class should not modify variables outside its definition. That would violate the encapsulation principle.

Comment: You have to change `some_number` as well. It's not magically linked to out class variable that when class variable changes the global one does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `some_number` is outside of the class, therefore it wouldn't change. The easiest way would be to avoid classes and modify the variable `some_number`. The alternative would be to drop `some_number` altogether and do the following:

```py
class Numbers:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def edit(self):
        self.number = self.number - 50
    def printNumber(self):
        print(self.number)
```

That would be called like this:

```py
number = Numbers(150)
number.edit()
number.printNumber()
```

There are many ways to edit that variable, but these are two potential methods.

As a caution, global variables can get tricky, but declaring it globally would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can access and alter `some_number` from the `global` scope by

```
class Numbers:
    def edit(self):
        global some_number
        some_number = some_number - 50

    def printNumber(self):
        print(some_number)
```

However, in general, the need to modify global variables usually points to a design problem ...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that what I was trying to do was use a global variable. I will research about why using global variables is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

You declared the variable `some_number` as a global variable. The whole point of adding the attribute `.number` to the `Numbers` class would be for it to be specific to each instance of the class.

You *can* change `some_number` as a side effect, but why would you want to?

Here's how you would if you have a good reason:

```
some_number = 200


class Numbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = some_number
    def edit(self):
        global some_number
        self.number = self.number - 50
        some_number = self.number
    def printNumber(self):
        print(self.number)


n = Numbers()
n.edit()
n.printNumber()
print(some_number)
```

More likely though, you'd want something like this:

```
some_number = 200


class Number:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def edit(self, change):
        self.number = self.number + change

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)


n = Number(some_number)
n.edit(-50)
print(n)
print(some_number)
```

It's generally a really bad idea to keep stuff around in global variables, unless there's a really good reason to have one value available to all of your program, with changes to that value affecting the entire program. And even in those cases, it's often better to explicitly pass the value around, instead of just referring to it, betting it has the correct value.

In the case of a class, if you do have a good reason, you should consider a class attribute instead of a global variable, which will keep the one value the same for all instances of the class, but at least there are no global side effects.